# Internal section refs not working in scrartcl

Tags: cross-referencing, scrartcl

I can't seem to get section references working in this scrartcl class article (from a template called Eisvogel). I usually use `\label{sec:intro}` and `\ref{sec:intro}` and it works fine, now I just see a blank space in the pdf. Am I missing a package?

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{unicode}{hyperref}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames,svgnames,x11names,table}{xcolor}
%
\documentclass[
  paper=a4,
  ,captions=tableheading,hyperref=true
]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,hyperref}
% Use setspace anyway because we change the default line spacing.
% The spacing is changed early to affect the titlepage and the TOC.
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.2}
\usepackage{iftex}
\ifPDFTeX
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage{textcomp} % provide euro and other symbols
\else % if luatex or xetex
  \usepackage{unicode-math} % this also loads fontspec
  \defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
  \defaultfontfeatures[\rmfamily]{Ligatures=TeX,Scale=1}
\fi
\usepackage{lmodern}
\ifPDFTeX\else
  % xetex/luatex font selection
\fi
% Use upquote if available, for straight quotes in verbatim environments
\IfFileExists{upquote.sty}{\usepackage{upquote}}{}
\IfFileExists{microtype.sty}{% use microtype if available
  \usepackage[]{microtype}
  \UseMicrotypeSet[protrusion]{basicmath} % disable protrusion for tt fonts
}{}
\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{KOMAClassName}{% if non-KOMA class
  \IfFileExists{parskip.sty}{%
    \usepackage{parskip}
  }{% else
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
    \setlength{\parskip}{6pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}}
}{% if KOMA class
  \KOMAoptions{parskip=half}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{default-linkcolor}{HTML}{A50000}
\definecolor{default-filecolor}{HTML}{A50000}
\definecolor{default-citecolor}{HTML}{4077C0}
\definecolor{default-urlcolor}{HTML}{4077C0}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm,includehead=true,includefoot=true,centering,]{geometry}
\usepackage{listings}
\newcommand{\passthrough}[1]{#1}
\lstset{defaultdialect=[5.3]Lua}
\lstset{defaultdialect=[x86masm]Assembler}
% add backlinks to footnote references, cf. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/302266/make-footnote-clickable-both-ways
\usepackage{footnotebackref}
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{3em} % prevent overfull lines
\providecommand{\tightlist}{%
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-\maxdimen} % remove section numbering
\ifLuaTeX
\usepackage[bidi=basic]{babel}
\else
\usepackage[bidi=default]{babel}
\fi
\babelprovide[main,import]{english}
% get rid of language-specific shorthands (see #6817):
\let\LanguageShortHands\languageshorthands
\def\languageshorthands#1{}
\ifLuaTeX
  \usepackage{selnolig}  % disable illegal ligatures
\fi
\IfFileExists{bookmark.sty}{\usepackage{bookmark}}{\usepackage{hyperref}}
\IfFileExists{xurl.sty}{\usepackage{xurl}}{} % add URL line breaks if available
\urlstyle{same}
\hypersetup{
  pdftitle={Vinaque sanguine metuenti cuiquam Alcyone fixus},
  pdfauthor={Author Name},
  pdflang={en},
  pdfsubject={Markdown},
  pdfkeywords={Markdown, Example},
  breaklinks=true,
  pdfcreator={LaTeX via pandoc with the Eisvogel template}}
\title{Vinaque sanguine metuenti cuiquam Alcyone fixus}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\providecommand{\subtitle}[1]{% add subtitle to \maketitle
  \apptocmd{\@title}{\par {\large #1 \par}}{}{}
}
\makeatother
\subtitle{Aesculeae domus vincemur et Veneris adsuetus lapsum}
\author{Author Name}
\date{2017-02-20}



%%
%% added
%%


%
% for the background color of the title page
%
\usepackage{pagecolor}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm,includehead=true,includefoot=true,centering]{geometry}

%
% break urls
%
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}

%
% When using babel or polyglossia with biblatex, loading csquotes is recommended
% to ensure that quoted texts are typeset according to the rules of your main language.
%
\usepackage{csquotes}

%
% captions
%
\definecolor{caption-color}{HTML}{777777}
\usepackage[font={stretch=1.2}, textfont={color=caption-color}, position=top, skip=4mm, labelfont=bf, singlelinecheck=false, justification=raggedright]{caption}
\setcapindent{0em}

%
% blockquote
%
\definecolor{blockquote-border}{RGB}{221,221,221}
\definecolor{blockquote-text}{RGB}{119,119,119}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\newmdenv[rightline=false,bottomline=false,topline=false,linewidth=3pt,linecolor=blockquote-border,skipabove=\parskip]{customblockquote}
\renewenvironment{quote}{\begin{customblockquote}\list{}{\rightmargin=0em\leftmargin=0em}%
\item\relax\color{blockquote-text}\ignorespaces}{\unskip\unskip\endlist\end{customblockquote}}

%
% Source Sans Pro as the default font family
% Source Code Pro for monospace text
%
% 'default' option sets the default
% font family to Source Sans Pro, not \sfdefault.
%
\ifnum 0\ifxetex 1\fi\ifluatex 1\fi=0 % if pdftex
    \usepackage[default]{sourcesanspro}
  \usepackage{sourcecodepro}
  \else % if not pdftex
    \usepackage[default]{sourcesanspro}
  \usepackage{sourcecodepro}

  % XeLaTeX specific adjustments for straight quotes: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/354887
  % This issue is already fixed (see https://github.com/silkeh/latex-sourcecodepro/pull/5) but the
  % fix is still unreleased.
  % TODO: Remove this workaround when the new version of sourcecodepro is released on CTAN.
  \ifxetex
    \makeatletter
    \defaultfontfeatures[\ttfamily]
      { Numbers   = \sourcecodepro@figurestyle,
        Scale     = \SourceCodePro@scale,
        Extension = .otf }
    \setmonofont
      [ UprightFont    = *-\sourcecodepro@regstyle,
        ItalicFont     = *-\sourcecodepro@regstyle It,
        BoldFont       = *-\sourcecodepro@boldstyle,
        BoldItalicFont = *-\sourcecodepro@boldstyle It ]
      {SourceCodePro}
    \makeatother
  \fi
  \fi

%
% heading color
%
\definecolor{heading-color}{RGB}{40,40,40}
\addtokomafont{section}{\color{heading-color}}
% When using the classes report, scrreprt, book,
% scrbook or memoir, uncomment the following line.
%\addtokomafont{chapter}{\color{heading-color}}

%
% variables for title, author and date
%
\usepackage{titling}
\title{Complexity and Green Bonds}
\author{Alexander Kartun-Giles and Nadia Ameli}
\date{1st of December 2023}

%
% tables
%

%
% remove paragraph indentation
%
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{6pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{3em}  % prevent overfull lines

%
%
% Listings
%
%


%
% general listing colors
%
\definecolor{listing-background}{HTML}{F7F7F7}
\definecolor{listing-rule}{HTML}{B3B2B3}
\definecolor{listing-numbers}{HTML}{B3B2B3}
\definecolor{listing-text-color}{HTML}{000000}
\definecolor{listing-keyword}{HTML}{435489}
\definecolor{listing-keyword-2}{HTML}{1284CA} % additional keywords
\definecolor{listing-keyword-3}{HTML}{9137CB} % additional keywords
\definecolor{listing-identifier}{HTML}{435489}
\definecolor{listing-string}{HTML}{00999A}
\definecolor{listing-comment}{HTML}{8E8E8E}

\lstdefinestyle{eisvogel_listing_style}{
  language         = java,
  numbers          = left,
  xleftmargin      = 2.7em,
  framexleftmargin = 2.5em,
  backgroundcolor  = \color{listing-background},
  basicstyle       = \color{listing-text-color}\linespread{1.0}%
                      \lst@ifdisplaystyle%
                      \small%
                      \fi\ttfamily{},
  breaklines       = true,
  frame            = single,
  framesep         = 0.19em,
  rulecolor        = \color{listing-rule},
  frameround       = ffff,
  tabsize          = 4,
  numberstyle      = \color{listing-numbers},
  aboveskip        = 1.0em,
  belowskip        = 0.1em,
  abovecaptionskip = 0em,
  belowcaptionskip = 1.0em,
  keywordstyle     = {\color{listing-keyword}\bfseries},
  keywordstyle     = {[2]\color{listing-keyword-2}\bfseries},
  keywordstyle     = {[3]\color{listing-keyword-3}\bfseries\itshape},
  sensitive        = true,
  identifierstyle  = \color{listing-identifier},
  commentstyle     = \color{listing-comment},
  stringstyle      = \color{listing-string},
  showstringspaces = false,
  escapeinside     = {/*@}{@*/}, % Allow LaTeX inside these special comments
  literate         =
  {á}{{\'a}}1 {é}{{\'e}}1 {í}{{\'i}}1 {ó}{{\'o}}1 {ú}{{\'u}}1
  {Á}{{\'A}}1 {É}{{\'E}}1 {Í}{{\'I}}1 {Ó}{{\'O}}1 {Ú}{{\'U}}1
  {à}{{\`a}}1 {è}{{\`e}}1 {ì}{{\`i}}1 {ò}{{\`o}}1 {ù}{{\`u}}1
  {À}{{\`A}}1 {È}{{\`E}}1 {Ì}{{\`I}}1 {Ò}{{\`O}}1 {Ù}{{\`U}}1
  {ä}{{\"a}}1 {ë}{{\"e}}1 {ï}{{\"i}}1 {ö}{{\"o}}1 {ü}{{\"u}}1
  {Ä}{{\"A}}1 {Ë}{{\"E}}1 {Ï}{{\"I}}1 {Ö}{{\"O}}1 {Ü}{{\"U}}1
  {â}{{\^a}}1 {ê}{{\^e}}1 {î}{{\^i}}1 {ô}{{\^o}}1 {û}{{\^u}}1
  {Â}{{\^A}}1 {Ê}{{\^E}}1 {Î}{{\^I}}1 {Ô}{{\^O}}1 {Û}{{\^U}}1
  {œ}{{\oe}}1 {Œ}{{\OE}}1 {æ}{{\ae}}1 {Æ}{{\AE}}1 {ß}{{\ss}}1
  {ç}{{\c c}}1 {Ç}{{\c C}}1 {ø}{{\o}}1 {å}{{\r a}}1 {Å}{{\r A}}1
  {€}{{\EUR}}1 {£}{{\pounds}}1 {«}{{\guillemotleft}}1
  {»}{{\guillemotright}}1 {ñ}{{\~n}}1 {Ñ}{{\~N}}1 {¿}{{?`}}1
  {…}{{\ldots}}1 {≥}{{>=}}1 {≤}{{<=}}1 {„}{{\glqq}}1 {“}{{\grqq}}1
  {”}{{''}}1
}
\lstset{style=eisvogel_listing_style}

%
% Java (Java SE 12, 2019-06-22)
%
\lstdefinelanguage{Java}{
  morekeywords={
    % normal keywords (without data types)
    abstract,assert,break,case,catch,class,continue,default,
    do,else,enum,exports,extends,final,finally,for,if,implements,
    import,instanceof,interface,module,native,new,package,private,
    protected,public,requires,return,static,strictfp,super,switch,
    synchronized,this,throw,throws,transient,try,volatile,while,
    % var is an identifier
    var
  },
  morekeywords={[2] % data types
    % primitive data types
    boolean,byte,char,double,float,int,long,short,
    % String
    String,
    % primitive wrapper types
    Boolean,Byte,Character,Double,Float,Integer,Long,Short
    % number types
    Number,AtomicInteger,AtomicLong,BigDecimal,BigInteger,DoubleAccumulator,DoubleAdder,LongAccumulator,LongAdder,Short,
    % other
    Object,Void,void
  },
  morekeywords={[3] % literals
    % reserved words for literal values
    null,true,false,
  },
  sensitive,
  morecomment  = [l]//,
  morecomment  = [s]{/*}{*/},
  morecomment  = [s]{/**}{*/},
  morestring   = [b]",
  morestring   = [b]',
}

\lstdefinelanguage{XML}{
  morestring      = [b]",
  moredelim       = [s][\bfseries\color{listing-keyword}]{<}{\ },
  moredelim       = [s][\bfseries\color{listing-keyword}]{</}{>},
  moredelim       = [l][\bfseries\color{listing-keyword}]{/>},
  moredelim       = [l][\bfseries\color{listing-keyword}]{>},
  morecomment     = [s]{<?}{?>},
  morecomment     = [s]{<!--}{-->},
  commentstyle    = \color{listing-comment},
  stringstyle     = \color{listing-string},
  identifierstyle = \color{listing-identifier}
}

%
% header and footer
%
\usepackage[headsepline,footsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\newpairofpagestyles{eisvogel-header-footer}{
  \clearpairofpagestyles
  \ihead*{Vinaque sanguine metuenti cuiquam Alcyone fixus}
  \chead*{}
  \ohead*{2017-02-20}
  \ifoot*{Author Name}
  \cfoot*{}
  \ofoot*{\thepage}
  \addtokomafont{pageheadfoot}{\upshape}
}
\pagestyle{eisvogel-header-footer}



%%
%% end added
%%

\begin{document}

%%
%% begin titlepage
%%
\begin{titlepage}
\newgeometry{top=2cm, right=4cm, bottom=3cm, left=4cm}
\tikz[remember picture,overlay] \node[inner sep=0pt] at (current page.center){\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{background.pdf}};
\newcommand{\colorRule}[3][black]{\textcolor[HTML]{#1}{\rule{#2}{#3}}}
\begin{flushleft}
\noindent
\\[-1em]
\color[HTML]{FFFFFF}
\makebox[0pt][l]{\colorRule[360049]{1.3\textwidth}{0pt}}
\par
\noindent

% The titlepage with a background image has other text spacing and text size
{
  \setstretch{2}
  \vfill
  \vskip -8em
  \noindent {\huge \textbf{\textsf{Complexity}}}
    \vskip 1em
  {\Large \textsf{Network science}}
    \vskip 2em
  \noindent {\Large \textsf{John} \vskip 0.6em \textsf{1st of December 2023}}
  \vfill
}


\end{flushleft}
\end{titlepage}
\restoregeometry
\pagenumbering{arabic}

%%
%% end titlepage
%%

% \maketitle

\section{Introduction}

Some text, see \ref{sec:market}.

\section{A summary of market challenges...}\label{sec:market}
The...
\end{document}
```

Comment: is that really the most minimal example you could make?

Comment: 400!! lines of code but I tried it and it stopped with `! Unable to load picture or PDF file 'background.pdf'.` and produced no output.

Comment: can use any pdf image, its a file from the template folder. See https://github.com/Wandmalfarbe/pandoc-latex-template, look for examples, then title-page-custom subfolder

Comment: I know its not minimal, but the pandoc thing made this from the markdown file (from the link above), and now I'm tangled up.

Comment: no you should remove the image reference not make everyone trying to help find an image, similarly you are asking people to trace tex behaviour but then add packages such as tikz which add literally thousands of extra lines that potentially need tracing. pandcoc may have made the original but _you_ posted this here and you could have reduced it before posting (see the form I posted in my answer this time)

Comment: The image reference is some clever background image for the title page. If I remove it I'll break the tex.

Comment: no you miss the point. You can keep the image and the custom fonts in your original document but here we don't care about that  we just need an example of the question you are asking about. You could have posted the file in my answer which required no tex knowledge, I just deleted lines of the preamble checking the problem still occurred until there was only one line left.

Answer (score 1):

A more reasonable example would be

```
\documentclass[
  paper=a4,
  ,captions=tableheading,hyperref=true
]{scrartcl}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-\maxdimen} % remove section numbering


\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

Some text, see \ref{sec:market}.

\section{A summary of market challenges...}\label{sec:market}
The...
\end{document}
```

As you have suppressed section numbering there is no number for `\ref` to generate.

Comment: Thank you. I don't know why they suppress this in the template by default!